# Tried to Mosaic Sentinel 2 images but my final image appeared with some overlapping Null data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, remote-sensing, sentinel-2, null

I'm working on an area that required me to use three sentinel images to fully cover it, I used the "mosaic to new raster" tool in ArcGIS to merge the three images and was surprised to find that the output image actually has the Null pixels from raster (3) instead of the fully covered imagery in raster (2) (pic related)

How can I fix this so it can look basically like "pic related 2"?

[image]

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: You can also use the [`sentinel-mosaic`](https://pypi.org/project/sentinel-mosaic/) module. See [this post](https://wsdookadr.github.io/posts/p5/) for more details on usage.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting the mosaic operator in the "Mosaic to New Raster" tool to FIRST where the output cell value of the overlapping areas will be the value from the first raster dataset mosaicked into that location